# export Usenet via IMAP or POP3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, cron, nntp

Which existing software has this capability?

I see that [news deliver](http://newsdeliver.sourceforge.net/) will send notification of usenet posts via e-mail, but is there software which will e-mail the actual usenet posts?  Something along the lines of [gmane](http://www.gmane.org/), but in reverse.

Possibly [GNU mailman](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/mailman-email-nntp-gate-16397.html) has this feature, but now I'm wondering whether [Leafnode](http://leafnode.sourceforge.net/) might also have that capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cyrus has the ability to export Usenet via IMAP and/or export shared
>   IMAP mailboxes via NNTP. This is made possible by a new NNTP daemon
>   which is included with Cyrus.

http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/docs/cyrus-imapd/2.4.9/install-netnews.php